# redis with timestamp + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, timestamp

We are using redis to display number of replies for a question asked in forum and there is a filter to filter the number of replies in a day,month,week,and year.

We are storing date only in redis key like `"question_#{question_id}_#{date with out timestamp}"` this date is UTC date.

Now we need to store timestamp in the key. If we add timestamp then it will create a new key for every reply.Please help us how to store number of replies in a particular day with redis.

Comment: This can help you http://blog.apiaxle.com/post/storing-near-realtime-stats-in-redis/

Answer (score 1):

We've done this before - you need to use a [Redis hash or list](http://redis.io/topics/data-types):

Basically, you'll need to store the `question` as the key, and then you can add replies as elements to that key:

> http://redis.io/commands/lpush
>
> REDIS.lpush("question_#{question_id}", Time.now.to_i)

There is a good resource here: http://yaychris.com/blog/2009/12/redis-part-2.html